# Filtering files in grunt copy

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I need to copy only some files.
How that can be done using grunt contrib copy?
Eg: My src folder will have `.js, .json, .md, .gzip` files out of which I need to copy `js` files only.

If both `.js` and `.min.js` are available, need to copy only `.min.js`
Can we add condition for this, like using regex or something like that?

Comment: Specify a function for the [`process`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) key.

Answer (score 0):

This will copy anything with a .js extension to the destination folder.

```
copy: {
    scripts: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src/files/',
            src: ['**/*.js'],
            dest: 'dist/js/'
        }]
    }
}
```

Regarding the .min.js files i'd probably suggest saving those files to a different folder titled minified or something.

If they're library files you're talking about and you aren't actually minifying them yourself then i'd suggest not keeping two versions of each and just have 1 version of each, or preferably the non minified version and then minifiy it in your distribution build so that you can debug the source easier.